# Adding a sentence word by word into a set using Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, set

I am trying to add each word of a sentence into a set using recursion in java. Punctuation does not matter.

My problem is that only the first word of the sentence is being printed after I print the list.

For example the sentence "One Two Three Four" would come out in my list as just [One].

```
public static TreeSet<String> getWordSet(String words) {
  TreeSet<String> result = new TreeSet<String>();
  int index = words.indexOf(" ");

  if (index < 0) {
     return result;
  } else {
     result.add(words.substring(0, index));
     getWordSet(words.substring(index + 1));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing or overlooking?

Comment: Your method will finally return a set containing only first word. You are not adding remaining words to set, in another words you are not using set returned by recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add result of returned value of your recursion function to your result set,(also you didnt consider the last word), something like this(I give explanation in the comments)

```
public static TreeSet<String> getWordSet(String words) {
      TreeSet<String> result = new TreeSet<String>();
      int index = words.indexOf(" ");

      if (index < 0 && words.length() == 0) {
         return result;
      }else if (index < 0 && words.length() > 0) { // here you didnt consider the last word
        result.add(words);
      } else {
         result = getWordSet(words.substring(index + 1)); //here we first get result of recursion then add our new value to the list
         result.add(words.substring(0, index));
      }
      return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take care of the scopes. Your TreeSet is a local variable, It is getting over-written every time you call the function with a new one.

Try declaring it as a global variable outside the function.

Comment: This is not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static TreeSet<String> result = new TreeSet<String>();

public static TreeSet<String> getWordSet(String words) {

  int index = words.indexOf(" ");

  if (index < 0 && words != null) {
       return result;
  } else if (index < 0 && words.length() > 0) {
       result.add(words);
  } else {
       result = getWordSet(words.substring(index + 1));
       result.add(words.substring(0, index));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll only address your dynamic programming as an exercise here, note that this kind of solution is not a good approach for solving your task.

In each invocation of your method, you are instantiating a new Set, which you will eventually throw away, and just return the very first one, which contains the first word. You will need to create the collection object outside the recursive method, then pass it around by reference, like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
    getWordSet("get word set", set);
    System.out.println(set.toString());

}

public static void getWordSet(String words, Set set) {
    int index = words.indexOf(" ");
    if (index < 0) {
        if (words.length() > 0) set.add(words);
    } else {
        set.add(words.substring(0, index));
        getWordSet(words.substring(index + 1), set);
    }       
}
```

The line `if (words.length() > 0) set.add(words);` will add the last word, in case the input string does not end with a space.

Demo here: http://ideone.com/ruEMjA

Answer (score 0):

Here's the recursive solution based on your original implementation.

```
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class RecursiveSplit {

    public static TreeSet<String> getWordSet(String sentence, TreeSet<String> mySet) {
        int index = sentence.indexOf(" ");
        if (index < 0)
            if (sentence.length()>0)
                index = sentence.length() - 1;
            else
                return mySet;

            mySet.add(sentence.substring(0, index));
            getWordSet(sentence.substring(index+1), mySet);

        return mySet;
    }

    public static TreeSet<String> getWordSetDriver(String sentence){
        TreeSet<String> blankSet = new TreeSet<String>();
        return getWordSet(sentence, blankSet); 
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s : getWordSetDriver("This is a sentence.")) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Solves the problem recursively.. Well I don't know why you intend to do that, but this is not the best way.